# Python decrypting Bug

Tags: python, encryption, tuples

I am trying to write a code that decrypts Caesers Cypher.
I don't have any syntax errors but am doing something wrong when applying the shift method (part of the Message class). Rather than applying a shift, it does nothing. 
I appreciate your feedback.

**This block runs error free and does not have any problems**

```
def apply_shift(self, shift):
    '''
    Applies the Caesar Cipher to self.message_text with the input shift.
    Creates a new string that is self.message_text shifted down the
    alphabet by some number of characters determined by the input shift        

    shift (integer): the shift with which to encrypt the message.
    0 <= shift < 26

    Returns: the message text (string) in which every character is shifted
         down the alphabet by the input shift
    '''
    dict1 =self.build_shift_dict(shift)
    encrypted = ""
    for i in self.message_text:
        if i in string.ascii_uppercase or i in string.ascii_lowercase:
            encrypted += dict1.get(i)
        else:
            encrypted += i
    return encrypted
```

**but this does**

```
class CiphertextMessage(Message):

    def __init__(self, text):
        '''
        Initializes a CiphertextMessage object

        text (string): the message's text

        a CiphertextMessage object has two attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
        '''
        Message.__init__(self, text)
        self.text = text


    def decrypt_message(self):
        '''
        Decrypt self.message_text by trying every possible shift value
        and find the "best" one. We will define "best" as the shift that
        creates the maximum number of real words when we use apply_shift(shift)
        on the message text. If s is the original shift value used to encrypt
        the message, then we would expect 26 - s to be the best shift value 
        for decrypting it.

        Note: if multiple shifts are  equally good such that they all create 
        the maximum number of you may choose any of those shifts (and their
        corresponding decrypted messages) to return

        Returns: a tuple of the best shift value used to decrypt the message
        and the decrypted message text using that shift value
        '''
        decoded = ()
        temp = ()
        words = self.text.split(' ')
        current = 0
        maximum = 0
        shiftValue = 0

        for l in range(26):
            current = 0
            words = self.apply_shift(l)
            for each in words.split():
                if each in self.valid_words:
                    current += 1                    
            if current > maximum:
                maximum = current
                decoded = temp

        return (decoded, shiftValue)
```

Comment: No character is going to be in `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase` at the same time.

Comment: Ha. I missed it. So "encrypted" is always equal unencrypted?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, very sharp eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very simple error:

You start with:

```
decoded = ()
temp = ()
```

and finish with:

```
        if current > maximum:
        maximum = current
        decoded = temp
```

But `temp` is used nowhere between.

So, you always return () in `decoded`

Comment: Lukas, you can "accept" answer and your question will not hang in "Unanswered"